# How to refresh Panic Transmit file list?

Tags: caching, ftp

I like the Panic Transmit client for FTP and SFTP, but have lost work a couple of times because the file list is cached and can't be completly refreshed easily.

The Refresh option in the View menu only refreshes the current directory, and doesn't do the subdirectories.

I've contacted Panic about this and got a response that it's the way it works, and they would like to change it but not in this release.  I've tried a couple of other FTP clients and find them lacking, eg. Fetch only shows the remote side and uses the Finder for the local side, this gets confusing quite quickly.

Does anyone know where Transmit keeps the cache of the file list so I can delete it and get a full refresh?

If not, it's back to the future with SCP, RSYNC and command line FTP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a crude workaround for this.  Transmit keeps the cache in memory, so if you quit the application it is cleared.  I just make a habit of always using quit from the dock before any usage that requires up to date timestamps.

Comment: As a note, this will impact which files get downloaded (from downloading a parent folder) as well.  DANGER!

Comment: @pfrank, That is correct, it can make a dog's breakfast of your transfer.

Comment: Thank you for this. I wish there was something like this built into the UI.